# Tensor product $(f'\circ f)\oplus(g'\circ g) = (f'\oplus g')\circ (f\oplus g)$ using modules definition when $i,j$ are homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, tensors

I'm trying to understand this proposition of my book, about modules and tensor product:
[image]

At the first line, when it says "The following proposition is an immediate consequence of the uniqueness of $k$ in the preceding rectangle", it's talking about this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxEda.jpg (which I won't post entirely here to not make this post extremely big). Also, onlt the bigger image is relevant, the first one is just for context

I tried to take $f, g$ by $i,j$ but I cannot see why $(f'\circ f)\oplus(g'\circ g) = (f'\oplus g')\circ (f\oplus g)$.

Comment: \oplus should instead be \otimes in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the notation be as in your question. There are two diagrams to consider. Firstly, by definition:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A\times B @>\tau>> A\otimes B\\
      @V (f'\circ f)\times (g'\circ g) V V @VV (f'\circ f )\otimes (g'\circ g) V\\
    A''\times B'' @>>\tau''> A''\otimes B''
      \end{CD} 
So this diagram gives you the equality $(f'\circ f )\otimes (g'\circ g) =\tau'' \circ ((f' \circ f) \otimes (g'\circ g))$

Prove that you can write $(f' \circ f) \times (g' \circ g) = f' \times g' \circ f \times g $ and expand the diagram like so:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A\times B @>\tau>> A\otimes B\\
      @V f\times g V V @VV f\otimes g V\\
    A\times B @>>\tau'> A'\otimes B'\\
      @V f'\times g' V V @VV f' \otimes g' V\\  
    A\times B @>>\tau''> A''\otimes B''\\
\end{CD}

So putting it all together gives you: $$\begin {align}(f'\circ f )\otimes (g'\circ g) =\tau'' \circ ((f' \circ f) \times (g' \circ g)) =\\ \tau'' \circ (f' \times g') \circ (f \times g) =\\(f' \otimes g') \circ (f \otimes g ) \end {align} $$

Strictly, you can proceed as in the last paragraph (ie without diagrams) but I thought I'd include the diagrams because that shows a process of reasoning which helps with these type of arguments.

Comment: Do you mean that $(f' \circ f) \times (g' \circ g) = f' \times g' \circ f \times g$ is a theorem? I need to prove it?

Comment: Yeah, it is the reason the proof works. It isn't hard to prove.